# Transform Navigation Based to Tab Bar Based app

Tags: iphone, tableview, tabbar

i've a problem.
I have to add an UITabBarController to my Navigation Based application. When i open MainWindow.xib and add a UITabBarController is all ok. But there's a problem. When i run the app the table view is completely disoriented and rows will not show correctly. This happen only with tab bar controller insert in MainWindow.xib . Without it all shows correctly.
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to adjust the frames of all your other views.    In your .xib files in interface builder, click the root View and go to attributes inspector (CMD-1), and in "Simulated User Interface elements / Bottom Bar" select "Tab Bar".  For any views created in code, you'll need to reduce the height of your frames perhaps as well to account for the smaller viewing area.

Comment: But how can i adjust the cell?All cell is completely overlapped and i'm not able to find a solution.

Comment: sounds like a row height problem -- are you returning the height of the row correctly?    It's hard to imagine how adding a tab bar would change that, but if things aren't right sometimes the problem can manifest itself in strange ways...

Comment: this is the screen that shows the problem https://files.me.com/andrea.lufino/b9blgx    my row's height is 75 and the style is grouped and not plain.

Comment: I found the solution!!! In add to your solution i set the cell height and the table view style programmatically! :)

Answer (score 0):

Generate a new tab bar project of the same name in a different directory, then copy over your delegate (.h and .m) and your MainWindow.xib. Without any code, it is most likely an error in your delegate.